# elevateZoom inner not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using elevate Zoom plugin to show zoomed images.
Plugin link is [here](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples)

Now i am facing the issue that zoom is not appearing as inner on the image as shown in Plugin examples.

The working demo can be seen here. 
[Live Wesbite](http://shop.brokencolor.in/test-product)

JS for zoom is as below

```
$("#zoom_03f").elevateZoom({
    constrainType: "height",
    zoomType: "inner",
    containLensZoom: true,
    gallery: 'gallery_01f',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    galleryActiveClass: "active"
});

$("#zoom_03f").bind("click", function(e) {
    var ez =
        $('#zoom_03').data('elevateZoom');
    $.fancybox(ez.getGalleryList());
    return false;
});

$("#gallery_01f a").click(function() {
    $("#zoom_03f").on("load", function() {
        var height = $("#zoom_03f").css("height");
        $(".zoomContainer").css("height", height);
        $(".zoomContainer .zoomWindow").css("height", height);
    });
});
```